# Yii2 upload some file but some file not

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In my Yii web I try to upload mp3 files but the weired is that some files get uploaded but some files not, I don't understand they have the same extension same size but don't uploaded ; My two files are

1 - beautiful_violin.mp3, size is 394 KB, type of file : MP3 Format Sound (.mp3)

2 - guitar_vs_violin.mp3, size is 400 KB, type of file : MP3 Format Sound (.mp3)

the 1st song upload , but the second song not uploaded; and it's happen with other mp3, upload some file and some files not.

I'm not using multiple upload, I upload one file per post; It's single file upload.

my model is :

```
public $PMediaFile;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['post_text'], 'string'],
        [['post_crdate', 'post_update'], 'safe'],
        [['post_status', 'post_likeplus', 'post_likemoin', 'permission_id', 'filestype_id', 'channel_id', 'user_id'], 'integer'],
        [['permission_id', 'filestype_id', 'channel_id', 'user_id'], 'required'],
        [['post_title', 'post_uid'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
        [['post_file', 'post_thimage', 'post_bgimage', 'post_cssclass', 'post_cssid'], 'string', 'max' => 350],
        [['post_icon'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['post_title'], 'unique'],
        [['PMediaFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'mp3', 'maxSize'=>2000000, 'tooBig' => 'Limit is 2M'],
        [['channel_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Channel::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['channel_id' => 'channel_id']],
        [['filestype_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Filestypes::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['filestype_id' => 'filestype_id']],
        [['permission_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Permission::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['permission_id' => 'permission_id']],
        [['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'user_id']],
    ];
}
```

in my controller

```
$isMember = AxChnPermission::ChannelMemberChnNID($this->chn_nid);

        if ($isMember)
        {
            $model = new PostMedia();       $model_Permission = new Permission; 

            $chn_id = $isMember->channel->channel_id;
            $chn_uid = $isMember->channel->channel_uid;
            $chn_folder = $isMember->channel->channel_folder;

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) 
            {
                AxPostMedia::CreateMedia($model, $chn_id, $chn_folder);
                header('Location: ' . Url::current() );
                exit;
            }

            return $this->render('/post-insert/widget/_formInsertMedia', [
                'model' => $model,
                'model_Permission' => $model_Permission,
            ]);
        }
```

AxPostMedia :

```
class AxPostMedia
{   
    public function UploadAudio($MPMEDIA, $MAUDIO, $ly_MediaName, $ly_MediaFolder)
    {   
        mkdir($ly_MediaFolder, 0777, true);

        $MPMEDIA->PMediaFile->saveAs($ly_MediaFolder .'/'. $ly_MediaName . '.' . $MPMEDIA->PMediaFile->extension);

        $MAUDIO->audio_path = $ly_MediaFolder .'/'. $ly_MediaName . '.' . $MPMEDIA->PMediaFile->extension;

        $MAUDIO->save(false);
    }

    public static function CreateMedia($MPMEDIA, $CHNID, $chn_folder)
    {
        $USRID = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $css_and_folder = AxValuePost::CssID();

        $MPMEDIA->user_id = $USRID;
        $MPMEDIA->channel_id = $CHNID;
        $MPMEDIA->post_uid = AxValuePost::PSTUID();
        $MPMEDIA->post_cssid = AxValuePost::CssID();
        $MPMEDIA->post_update = time();

        $ly_MediaName = AxValuePost::FileName();

        $MPMEDIA->PMediaFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($MPMEDIA, 'PMediaFile');

        if ($MPMEDIA->PMediaFile->extension == 'mp3')
        {
            $MPMEDIA->filestype_id = 300;
        }

        $ly_MediaFolder = AxValuePost::PostFolder($chn_folder, $css_and_folder, $MPMEDIA->PMediaFile->extension);

        if ($MPMEDIA->PMediaFile->extension === 'mp3')
        {
            if ($MPMEDIA->save())
            {

            $MAUDIO = new Audio;

            $MAUDIO->post_id = $MPMEDIA->post_id;
            $MAUDIO->channel_id = $CHNID;
            $MAUDIO->user_id = $USRID;

            (new self)->UploadAudio($MPMEDIA, $MAUDIO, $ly_MediaName, $ly_MediaFolder);
            }
        }
        return $MPMEDIA->save(false);
    }
}
```

my view is :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['id' => 'upload-media-form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'PMediaFile')->fileInput() ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'post_text')->textarea(['rows' => 2]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'permission_id')->dropdownList($model_Permission->PermissionType()) ?>

                <div class="text-right"><?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?></div>

                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting this behavior while uploading multiple files atonce or one by one, and does it display any error when it does not upload the file? is this happening in a sequence, means, on every 2nd or 3rd try or happening for specific files?

Comment: upload file one by one I'm not using multiple upload

Comment: if you have `ffmpeg` installed you can check if the file is of valid mp3 format.

Comment: I will try to install it